# Set Theory: Tree Property

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, trees, infinitary-combinatorics

Why does the tree property hold for regular cardinals but not singular cardinals?
(I.e. There exists a tree of height $\kappa$ with countable levels and no cofinal branch for $\kappa$ a singular cardinal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

---

First of all, the tree property **doesn't** hold of regular cardinals in general. For example, it provably fails for $\kappa=\omega_1$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aronszajn_tree), and getting the tree property at $\omega_2$ has high consistency strength relative to ZFC - it is equiconsistent with the existence of a **weakly compact** cardinal. In fact, in $ZFC+V=L$, **every** successor cardinal fails to have the tree property - thus, in $ZFC+V=L+$"there are no inaccessibles," *the tree property never holds of any uncountable cardinal at all*.

---

Second, you've stated the tree property wrong: the point is not that the levels are *countable*, but rather that they are *small* (of size $<\kappa$). (Also, we usually demand that the tree itself have cardinality $\kappa$, if I remember correctly, but this actually doesn't matter: if I have a tree of height $\kappa$ with levels of size $<\kappa$ and no $\kappa$-length branches, I can prune it down to such a tree with size $\kappa$ - just fix a set of $\kappa$-many nodes, the supremum of whose heights is $\kappa$, and look at the induced subtree.)

---

Finally, here's why the tree property can never hold of $\kappa$ singular. Let $\lambda=cf(\kappa)<\kappa$, let $\{\alpha_\eta: \eta\in\lambda\}$ be a cofinal subset of $\kappa$, and consider the following tree on $\kappa$:

$$T=\{f\in \kappa^{<\kappa}: f(0)<\lambda\mbox{ and }\vert f\vert<\alpha_{f(0)}\mbox{ and } f(\eta)=0 \mbox{ for all }0<\eta<\vert f\vert\}\cup\{\emptyset\}.$$ Basically, $T$ consists of $\lambda$-many branches, with the $\eta$th such branch of height $\alpha_\eta$. Then the height of $T$ is clearly $\sup\{\alpha_\eta: \eta<\lambda\}=\kappa$, but each level is of cardinality at most $\lambda$.

Comment: A remark in an exercise in Set Theory by Kunen is that if there is an $\omega_2$- Aronszajn tree then $\omega_2$ is Mahlo in $ L ,$ which I think is due to K.MacAloon. Sorry I can't re-locate it in Kunen, and the index is rudimentary. & I don't know what the current  knowledge is.

Comment: @user254665 Are you sure you have that right? I would expect the assumption to be "there is **not** an $\omega_2$-Aronszajn tree." For instance, I'm pretty sure $CH$ implies that there is an $\omega_2$-Aronszajn tree, and Wikipedia seems to agree with me . . .

Comment: As i said i t found it in the book again, but i know it's in there, but i could have not recalled it accurately.

Comment: @user254665 See https://books.google.com/books?id=RBrWwKVbmMUC&pg=PA386&lpg=PA386&dq=Aronszajn+Mahlo+in+L&source=bl&ots=mtp61gtrtV&sig=Up0XTV3Jif-IJDgT6QSCOVX88KQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjfxb_hrq3LAhUW8mMKHb7bBMkQ6AEIQDAF#v=onepage&q=Aronszajn%20Mahlo%20in%20L&f=false. It is indeed not as you recall it. Also, that's just from "no **special** Aronszajn trees on $\omega_2$": the assumption "$\omega_2$ has the tree property" is in fact equiconsistent with a weakly compact.

Comment: Thanks. I was just thinking that  I had it wrong.

Comment: This is a very minor issue, but since you require $f(0) < \lambda$ one might think that you don't consider $\emptyset$ as an element of your tree (and I'm pretty sure that you want that to be the root). You may also want to say that you order your tree by inclusion - just in case someone who isn't very familiar with these constructions stumbles upon your answer. PS: That's one ugly tree, but a beautiful answer ;-)